# Laravel: BadMethodCallException with message 'Method update does not exist.'

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

When I try to update a model with this code:

```
public function updateMixedtape($slug, Request $request)
{
    $mix = Mix::where('slug', $slug)->get();
    $mix->update($request->all());
    return redirect('dashboard/mixes');
}
```

I get an error that method `update` doesn't exist. However if I modify my view to send a `radio_show_id` instead of `slug` and try to change the code to something like this:

```
public function updateMixedtape(Request $request)
{
    $mix = Mix::findOrFail($request->radio_show_id);
    $mix->update($request->all());
    return redirect('dashboard/mixes');
}
```

The code executes without any errors.

What puzzles me is that if I do something like `return $mix;` before the line where I call the `update` method, I get similar data for both methods.

Comment: with get()  a Collection() is returned. Not a model. Just use first()  instead of get() in your case

Comment: Thanks.. It worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shock_gone_wild has suggested in the comment section of my question `$mix = Mix::where('slug', $slug)->get();` is returning a collection and not a model. This is because a `Model::where()` method can return zero, one or many records depending on whether or not there are records that meet the set condition.

As suggested I used `$mix = Mix::where('slug', $slug)->first();` instead to get the first record that meets the condition.